# Android: Facebook logout function

Tags: java, android, facebook, logout

I am using the Facebook sdk 3.8, and I want to create a logout function. I have this button:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/button_logout"
   android:layout_width="130dp"
   android:layout_height="35dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
   android:text="Logout" />
```

I have looked for solutions and tried the Facebook tutorials, but I cant get it to work, so I am wondering is it possible to, when this button is clicked, to clear the login data from the app, and then redirect to the MainActivity?

This is what I have tried so far without success:

```
Button s = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_logout);
s.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
       Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
       session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
       Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Any help and tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null) {
    session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
}
```

You should clear other user data saved in sharedPreferences, sqlite, etc...
Maybe you should call to finish() when you call to startActivity